# Google Oauth city issue

Tags: curl, google-plus, google-oauth

When i am trying to execute this request using curl

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=$access_token
```

with scope

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

i receive next

```
{ ["id"]=> string(21) "someid" 
  ["name"]=> string(16) "name" 
  ["given_name"]=> string(9) "given_name" 
  ["family_name"]=> string(6) "family_name" 
  ["link"]=> string(45) "profile url" 
  ["picture"]=> string(92) "picture link" 
  ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" 
}
```

I have to receive current location and placed lived. I found this one 
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get and when i using this form (it show me my city), it says me request `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/108293047925229351365?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`. I tried it, but always getting error. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[People: get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) returns a [person resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource) as far as I can see there is no current location in the person resource.  IF you test it using the try it section at the bottom you will also notice that unless the person in question has the places lived set to **public** they will not be returned.

If you go to [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) at the bottom try it. 108293047925229351365 add the user id you will see the info is returning now.

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{UserID}?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

[image]

Comment: i set current place as public, but i can't receive it anyway

Comment: Assuming you didn't change the user id the one you posted 108293047925229351365  is a user called Alexander Petrov who does not have places set to public.  if you check mine I do  https://plus.google.com/u/0/117200475532672775346/about

Comment: I set it before, but i playing with accessing. Now i set it public, but anyway there are not place [link](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108293047925229351365/about)

Comment: the data is returning now.  I posted a picture.

Comment: allright. how i can get it using curl? i tried this https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{UserID}?key={YOUR_API_KEY}, it says error:)  
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}

Answer (score -1):

It is mine inattention. Sorry, i forgot to make enable Google+ API for my app.